# change the column value based on the multiple columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am developing code for searching a keyword in the given data.
    for example, I have a data in column A & I want to find if 
    the substring is present in the row if yes give me that keyword against 
    the data, if that keyword is not present then give me 'blank'.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/606736.CTS/Desktop/Keyword.xlsx")

# dropping null value columns to avoid errors 
data.dropna(inplace = True)
# Converting the column to uppercase
data["Uppercase"]= data["Skill"].str.upper()

# Below is the keywords I want to search in the data
sub =['MEMORY','PASSWORD','DISK','LOGIN','RESET']
# I have used the below code, which is creating multiple columns & 
giving me the boolean output
for keyword in sub:
data[keyword] = data.astype(str).sum(axis=1).str.contains(keyword)
 # what I want is, search the keyword if it exits give me the keyword 
  name else blank
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including some data and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
data['Keyword'] = np.nan
for i in sub:
    data.loc[(data['Uppercase'].apply(lambda x: i in x.split(' ')) & (data['Keyword'].isna()), 'Keyword'] = i
```

Comment: HI sir, it is working fine & in fact, I tried this, but one condition would be, for example, if I have 3 keywords to be searched in cell A1 & 2 keywords are found in cell A1, it should give me the first keyword as an output in keyword column.

Comment: " Just to be clear if cell A1 has (PASSWORD RESET) & my search keyword is (PASSWORD, LOGIN, RESET), now if I run this code the output in the keyword column is "RESET". But  I wanted the first-word "PASSWORD", as an output. Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Just update the code. This should give what you want.

Comment: Hi Clide, Much thanks for your help, this was very helpful for me.

Comment: Hi Clide, one problem, I am facing now is, I want the code to search for the complete word, not the string in the word.  for example, my search keyword is 'AD', which should search in 'IE UPGRADE', this code output is giving me 'AD', instead of nan.

Comment: Clide i am struck here - for example, i have dataframe with 2 columns "Problem"  "Keyword". i have a separate CSV file where all the keywords are stored( 20 columns), now code should check what is the keyword row item, if the keyword row item is “Password ”, then the Password column of the CSV file should be searched In the problem column & search output to store in  separate column.

Comment: it know its little confusing, let me know if you need any additional info

Comment: Could u send some example and expected result? May be in a new question

Comment: Would this help or any other example you would need

Comment: HI Clide - Attached question for your perusal